# Rake task not saving or creating new record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake, rakefile

I've created a ruby script that executes fine if I run it from Console.

The script fetches some information from various websites and saves it to my database table.

However, when I want to turn the code into a rake task, the code still runs, but it does not save any new records. I don't get any errors from the rake either.

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be           available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks

require './crawler2.rb'
task :default => [:crawler]

task :crawler do

### ###

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

start = Time.now

$a = 0

sites = ["http://www.nytimes.com","http://www.news.com"]

for $a in 0..sites.size-1

url = sites[$a] 

$i = 75

$error = 0

avoid_these_links = ["/tv", "//www.facebook.com/"]

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    links = doc.css("a")
    hrefs = links.map {|link| link.attribute('href').to_s}.uniq.sort.delete_if {|href| href.empty?}.delete_if {|href| avoid_these_links.any? { |w| href =~ /#{w}/ }}.delete_if {|href| href.size < 10 }

#puts hrefs.length

#puts hrefs

for $i in 0..hrefs.length
    begin

        #puts hrefs[60] #for debugging)

    #file = open(url)
    #doc = Nokogiri::HTML(file) do

        if hrefs[$i].downcase().include? "http://"

            doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(hrefs[$i]))

        else 

            doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url+hrefs[$i]))

        end 

        image = doc.at('meta[property="og:image"]')['content']
        title = doc.at('meta[property="og:title"]')['content']
        article_url = doc.at('meta[property="og:url"]')['content']
        description = doc.at('meta[property="og:description"]')['content']
        category = doc.at('meta[name="keywords"]')['content']

        newspaper_id = 1 


        puts "\n"
        puts $i
        #puts "Image: " + image
        #puts "Title: " + title
        #puts "Url: " + article_url
        #puts "Description: " + description
        puts "Catory: " + category

            Article.create({ 
            :headline => title, 
            :caption => description, 
            :thumbnail_url => image, 
            :category_id => 3, 
            :status => true, 
            :journalist_id => 2, 
            :newspaper_id => newspaper_id, 
            :from_crawler => true,
            :description => description,
            :original_url => article_url}) unless Article.exists?(original_url: article_url)

        $i +=1

        #puts $i #for debugging

        rescue
        #puts "Error here: " + url+hrefs[$i] if $i < hrefs.length
        $i +=1    # do_something_* again, with the next i
        $error +=1

    end 

end

puts "Page: " + url
puts "Articles: " + hrefs.length.to_s
puts "Errors: " + $error.to_s

$a +=1

end

finish = Time.now

diff = ((finish - start)/60).to_s

puts diff + " Minutes"


### ###


end
```

The code executes fine, if I save the file as crawler.rb and open it in Console by doing --> " load './crawler2.rb' ". When I use the exact same code in a rake task, I get no new records.

Comment: feels like there's something missing here. the `task :crawler do` is never closed with an `end`. Is the Article creation actually inside the task? Indentation suggests maybe not?

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm afraid that's not it. I tested out with some print/puts statements and these work perfectly as well. It's like the code just skips over the .create part. I don't know if I use Rake the wrong way or if the syntax is wrong?

Comment: Syntax is wrong. a 'do' requires and 'end' somewhere.

Comment: I¨ve updated the question. I'm not missing an 'end' :/

Comment: To debug, change `Article.create` to `Article.create!`. It will raise error if something goes wrong. Also, is the DB to which you're writing the same in both cases?

Comment: Please format your code to ruby standards, and eliminate scrolling.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Comment: I've formatted the code accordingly. I tried with Article.create! which does not throw any arrows. It still just runs the scripts and prints the outputs, but no records are created in the databse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.

I need to remove:

```
require './crawler2.rb'
task :default => [:crawler]
```

and instead edit the following:

```
task :crawler => :environment do
```

Now the crawler runs every ten minutes with a bit of help from Heroku scheduler :-)

Thanks for the help guys - and sorry for the bad formatting. Hope this answer may help others.